# Passing 2 parameters to $http.post return error 404

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am trying to pass 2 value to the function in `RestAPI` through $http.post method when the $http.post method is called browser console shows error

```
http://localhost:8550/api/Servicesapi/UpdateEmployeeServices/ 404 (Not Found)
```

But when i pass single value function executes successfully and no error is shown

**here is my Angular Code**

```
var servicedata = JSON.stringify($scope.services);
var sdata = { id: Id, services: servicedata };
$http.post('/api/Servicesapi/UpdateEmployeeServices', sdata)
.then(function (result) {
//Success
  }, function() {
//Error
});
```

**Here is API Function**

```
[AcceptVerbs,HttpPost]
public void UpdateEmployeeServices(string id,Service[] services)
{
     //some Implementation       
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `services: $scope.services`, without JSON.stringify? Right now part of request params is just a param string, and another is json, so server just cannot parse it

Comment: I dont see this same issue... I get a 404 independent of the data i pass.  Sample plunkr  http://plnkr.co/edit/yAGmz7MhJoQRFDSzAK7N?p=preview

Comment: can you show us your routes file ?

Comment: @Aviatrix is hinting toward what is probably the problem.  Do you have another route wihtin that controller that just takes in an int ?  And he was probably correct below that your not posting something that matches the signature of your function.  If your route is /UpdateEmployeeServices/id you just need to be posting services.

Comment: `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);`
currently using default route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is(based on a **major** asumption that your route is actually `UpdateEmployeeSrvices/<id>`):

```
//var servicedata = JSON.stringify($scope.services);
//var sdata = { id: Id, services: servicedata };
$http.post('/api/Servicesapi/UpdateEmployeeServices/'+ Id , $scope.services)
   .then(function (result) {
     //Success
   }, function() {
      //Error
})
```